# GCC (MinGW) Linker Fails When Trying to Use GetProcessImageFileName

Tags: c++, c, winapi, gcc, mingw

I am trying to retrieve the name of remote processes using "GetProcessImageFileName". However, the GCC (MinGW) linker fails with the following error(s):

```
<source_file>.c: In function '<function_name>':
 warning: implicit declaration of function 'GetProcessImageFileName' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 GetProcessImageFileName(hProcess, szProcessName, MAX_PATH);
 ^
undefined reference to `GetProcessImageFileName'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried compiling with "-lPsapi" and "-lKernel32" but I get the same results. "GetProcessImageFileName" is declared in "Psapi.h".

I'm using a machine with Windows 7 Professional 64-bit and GCC 4.8.1. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Only thing I can think of, without actually trying anything, is you're passing a "narrow" string into the Unicode version of the function. Do you have `UNICODE` defined, and what is the type of `szProcessName`? I'm guessing "yes" and `char*` or `std::string`. Some source would be nice.

Comment: The warning is from the compiler, not the linker, and it means that `GetProcessImageFileName` hasn't been declared.  So you need to include the correct header.  If the function is not in the header you may need a more recent version of mingw, or mingw itself may need updating.

Comment: @arx Vanilla MinGW lacks pretty much anything new in XP, such as `GetProcessImageFileName()`. If that's what XerZetZip is using, he'll need to switch to mingw-w64. It's a shame that we still today have this issue with people using the wrong MinGW...

Comment: @andlabs Cheers, I've expanded that into an answer.

Comment: @icabod szProcessName is an array of `char`s

Comment: @andlabs I included the correct header file `psapi.h` and `-lpsapi` and `-lKernel32` in the command line. I try to keep MinGW up to data but it appears there's no new developments. I also tried to get MinGW-w64 but had extensive issue getting it to work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you define the macro `_WIN32_WINNT` to be [larger or equal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `0x0501` (Windows XP, minimum system supports [`GetProcessImageFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Either use the switch `-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501` or before you include the headers:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
```